# Microsoft Sync Framework for File (Client) and SQL Server Database (Server) synchronization

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to implement the syncing solution using Microsoft Sync Framework. The server will be SQL server database contains the documents in FileStream and client will be the File system (Windows OS). 
I have seen file synchronization provider with the Azure Blob Storage/Custom provider. But have not seen this. Do anybody have any idea on this.
My application scenario is :The database server contains the File/Documents in the form of byte array by the FileStream mechanism from SQL server.
And the Sync activity will syncronize the documents from SQL server to any given file system.
Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will have to build your own custom provider to get this working. the existing file sync provider and sql sync provider doesnt work with each other.

Comment: My goodness, is it so. Dont any body have encountered the same issue. Do you have any sample code to suggest the same?